# What this edit actually changes where nothing is modified, but the whole text is highlighted?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've the following [review edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9191930):

[image: stackoverflow review - Approve, Reject, Skip]

where the whole text is highlighted, but no visible changes are present.

There is only *markdown* tab (no *rendered output* as usual for some reason), but having *markdown* mode I should see the exact changes, but I don't.

What's going on in here? Secondly, should I Reject it or Skip it? Or accept it (as there seems to be some users who already accepted it)?

Comment: weird.  Tag wikis are weird.

Comment: How appropriate that the OP was "my head hurts"....

Comment: To my opinion this should be rejected since this edit adds nothing useful and comment is misleading, too. Why other users approved it, not sure

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only change is a trailing space. Reject.

Comment: The edit has been [rejected.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9191930)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Where do you see a trailing space?

Comment: @kenorb: Comparing `$(".post-text.inserted").text()` with `$(".post-text.deleted").text()` in the console.

Comment: I think, for some reason, the excerpt got submitted as a new edit, even though it didn't change, when the editor [submitted an edit for the tag wiki.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9979726/revisions) They may not have even known it went through. (This is just a guess, as I've never made a tag wiki edit myself and therefore don't know if it would behave this way.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Doesn't a trailing whitespace usually show up as highlighted in the difference?

Comment: @Kendra: Yes, it does; I'm not sure what the problem is here. (There's an element at the end that shows up that's supposed to be highlighted, but I guess it's just whitespace or something, maybe zero-width.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy If this would be just a trailing space, the whole paragraph wouldn't be highlighted I guess, but instead the left has the light-red and the right side has light-green background indicating that some change has been applied to the paragraph. But maybe it could be just a trailing space.

Comment: @kenorb: I see no highlight at all.

Comment: And of course, [two reviewers approved it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9191930).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: to help restore your faith in the review system, note the fact that this edit was approved by two users has not gone unnoticed...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The edit added a single trailing newline.

Since the review page uses an XHR to fetch its contents, you can use your browser's dev tools to inspect the "pure" response (as opposed to the DOM view, where formatting has been done):

```
{
    "isUnavailable": true,
    "instructions": "<div class=\"review-status\">\r\n                    <strong>\r\n<span style=\"color: #A00;\">Rejected</span> <span title=\"2015-08-17 19:52:24Z\" class=\"relativetime\">14 hours ago</span>:                    </strong>\r\n    </div>    \r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/93306/will-eddins\" class=\"comment-user\">Will Eddins</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-08-17 19:52:24Z\" class=\"relativetime\">14 hours ago</span>: <b>Reject</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n                    <div class=\"rejection-reason cool\">This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.</div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/93161/robert-love\" class=\"comment-user\">Robert Love</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-08-17 19:08:22Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>: <b>Reject</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n                    <div class=\"rejection-reason cool\">This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.</div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/822711/popnoodles\" class=\"comment-user\">Popnoodles</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-08-17 18:35:48Z\" class=\"relativetime\">15 hours ago</span>: <b>Reject</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n                    <div class=\"rejection-reason cool\">This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.</div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/830680/clive\" class=\"comment-user\">Clive</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-08-17 18:13:08Z\" class=\"relativetime\">16 hours ago</span>: <b>Approve</b>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class=\"review-results\">\r\n            <a href=\"/users/795990/anand-s-kumar\" class=\"comment-user\">Anand S Kumar</a> reviewed this <span title=\"2015-08-17 17:29:32Z\" class=\"relativetime\">16 hours ago</span>: <b>Approve</b>\r\n        </div>",
    "moreInstructions": "<p><strong>Reviewer Stats</strong></p>\r\n    <ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/93306/will-eddins\">Will Eddins</a> has approved 958 edit suggestions and rejected 421 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/93161/robert-love\">Robert Love</a> has approved 108 edit suggestions and rejected 21 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/822711/popnoodles\">Popnoodles</a> has approved 306 edit suggestions and rejected 128 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/830680/clive\">Clive</a> has approved 153 edit suggestions and rejected 42 edit suggestions</li>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/795990/anand-s-kumar\">Anand S Kumar</a> has approved 784 edit suggestions and rejected 265 edit suggestions</li>\r\n    </ul>\r\n        <p><strong>Editor Stats</strong></p>\r\n        <ul>\r\n\r\n    <li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/4195066/coder55\">Coder55</a> had 10 edit suggestions approved, and 3 edit suggestions rejected</li>\r\n        </ul>",
    "actions": [
    {
        "type": 254,
        "name": "Next",
        "description": "review next item",
        "tooltip": "review next item",
        "disabled": false
    }],
    "reviewTaskId": 9191930,
    "content": "<div class=\"mainbar-full\">\r\n\r\n    <div id=\"suggested-edit-2038493\" class=\"answer-summary question-summary suggested-edit post-type-id-4\" style=\"padding-bottom: 30px;\">\r\n        <div class=\"post-id\" style=\"display: none;\">9979727</div>\r\n                    <div class=\"diff-choices\">\r\n                <a href=\"#\" id=\"full-diff\" class=\"action sidebyside-markdown-diff selected\" title=\"Show the markdown source diffs side-by-side\">markdown</a>\r\n                <br class=\"cbt\" />\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n        <table>\r\n            <tr>\r\n            <td class=\"votecell\">\r\n                <div class=\"vote\">\r\n                    <div class=\"vote-count-post\">\r\n                        0\r\n                    </div>\r\n                    <div style=\"font-weight: normal;\">\r\n                       votes\r\n                    </div>\r\n\r\n                </div>\r\n            </td>\r\n            <td>\r\n                <div class=\"summary\">\r\n                    <div class=\"revision\">\r\n                        Comment: <span class=\"revision-comment\" title=\"comment on this suggested edit\">mentioned swagger flexibility</span>\r\n                    </div>\r\n                    <h2>\r\n<a href=\"/questions/tagged/swagger\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;swagger&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">swagger</a>                                    <a href=\"/tags/swagger/info\" class=\"question-hyperlink\">tag wiki excerpt</a>\r\n                    </h2>\r\n\r\n                            <div class=\"body-diffs\">\r\n<table class=\"full-diff \"><tr><td class=\"post-text content deleted\"><div>Swagger is a specification and framework implementation for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.</div></td><td class=\"post-text content inserted\"><div>Swagger is a specification and framework implementation for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.<span class=\"diff-add\">\n</span></div></td></tr></table>                            </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n                    <table class=\"user-info-actions\">\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <td class=\"post-signature current-owner\">\r\n                                <div class=\"started\">\r\n                                    <div class=\"user-info user-hover\">\r\n    <div class=\"user-action-time\">\r\n        created <span title=\"2012-04-02 16:02:51Z\" class=\"relativetime\">Apr 2 '12 at 16:02</span>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"user-gravatar32\">\r\n        <a href=\"/users/681807/my-head-hurts\"><div class=\"gravatar-wrapper-32\"><img src=\"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f12af4788f5589d79a19472c5e1c40bd?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG\" alt=\"\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\"></div></a>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"user-details\">\r\n        <a href=\"/users/681807/my-head-hurts\">My Head Hurts</a><br>\r\n        <span class=\"reputation-score\" title=\"reputation score 20836\" dir=\"ltr\">20.8k</span><span title=\"12 gold badges\"><span class=\"badge1\"></span><span class=\"badgecount\">12</span></span><span title=\"40 silver badges\"><span class=\"badge2\"></span><span class=\"badgecount\">40</span></span><span title=\"79 bronze badges\"><span class=\"badge3\"></span><span class=\"badgecount\">79</span></span>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n                                </div>\r\n                            </td>\r\n                            <td class=\"gutter\"></td>\r\n                            <td class=\"post-signature suggested-owner\">\r\n                                <div class=\"started\">\r\n<div class=\"user-info \">\r\n    <div class=\"user-action-time\">\r\n        proposed <span title=\"2015-08-17 16:50:04Z\" class=\"relativetime\">17 hours ago</span> \r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"user-gravatar32\">\r\n        <a href=\"/users/4195066/coder55\"><div class=\"gravatar-wrapper-32\"><img src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrTFh.jpg?s=32&amp;g=1\" alt=\"\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\"></div></a>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"user-details\">\r\n        <a href=\"/users/4195066/coder55\">Coder55</a><br>\r\n        <span class=\"reputation-score\" title=\"reputation score \" dir=\"ltr\">394</span><span title=\"1 silver badge\"><span class=\"badge2\"></span><span class=\"badgecount\">1</span></span><span title=\"12 bronze badges\"><span class=\"badge3\"></span><span class=\"badgecount\">12</span></span>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>                                </div>\r\n                            </td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                    </table>\r\n                </div>\r\n            </td>\r\n            </tr>\r\n        </table>\r\n\r\n      <br class=\"cbt\" />\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<br class=\"cbt\" />",
    "actionDelay": 0,
    "postId": 9979727,
    "badgeProgress": "473",
    "suggestedEditCount": 30
}
```

This is the old text:

```
<td class=\"post-text content deleted\"><div>Swagger is a specification and framework implementation for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.</div></td>
```

And this is the new one (scroll right):

```
<td class=\"post-text content inserted\"><div>Swagger is a specification and framework implementation for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.<span class=\"diff-add\">\n</span></div></td>
```

And this is only my opinion, but I would totally reject such edits for the very reason this one has been rejected now:

> **No improvement whatsoever**

Comment: More info... It looks like the user was [editing the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9191929).  Perhaps they started to make changes to the excerpt and then decided not to, but accidentally left a new line in.

Comment: @Siguza This rejection does not 'harm' the editor, does it? (especially in light of Jason's remark here)

Comment: @JanDoggen I guess it counts just like any other rejected edit. If the user has many other edits rejected (although we don't know the exact definition of "many"), they will eventually receive a 7-day ban from suggesting edits. Whether that "harms" the user is a different question, though. Most likely, the user will not receive a ban for this at all, but if they submit such edits so excessively that they do get a ban, then that's probably a good thing, because it might teach them to use the "cancel" button instead of "save", thus reducing the time reviewers spend on reviewing meaningless edits.